# Array in private scope from public scope but variable is not in same class ['d' does not have a type]

Tags: c++, variables, compiler-errors, scope, declaration

Run the code to see where the problem lies.

[Error] 'd' does not name a type

I tried declaring the variable directly in public but it kept popping up with more errors.

There seems to be apparently no fix, since googling didn't help much in the process.

It'd be super helpful if someone could help me figure out where the problem is.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class array1{
    protected:
        static int a[50];
    public:
        int n1;
        void getNum1(void)
        {
            cout<<"how many numbers?"<<endl;
            cin>>n1;
            for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
            {
                cout<<"enter le number"<<endl;
                cin>>a[i];
            }
        }

        int* retNum1(void)
        {
            return a;
        }
};

class array2{
    protected:
        static int b[50];
    public:
        int n2;
        void getNum2(void)
        {
            cout<<"how many numbers?"<<endl;
            cin>>n2;
            for(int i=0;i<n2;i++)
            {
                cout<<"enter le number"<<endl;
                cin>>b[i];
            }
        }

        int* retNum2(void)
        {
            return b;
        }
};

class conarray:public array1, public array2{
    private:
        int c[100],d;
        //int d;
    public:
        d=0;
        void disp()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                cin>>c[i];
            }
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                cout<<c[i]<<endl;
            }
            cout<<d;
        }
        //int d = 0;
        /*void merge(void)
        {
            int *nn1 = retNum1();
            int *nn2 = retNum2();
            for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
            {
                c[d]=nn1[i];
                d++;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<n2;i++)
            {
                c[d]=nn2[i];
                d++;
            }
        }
        void display(void)
        {
            cout<<"NUMBERS IN ARRAY:"<<endl;
            for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
            {
                cout<<c[i]<<endl;
            }
        }*/

};

int main()
{
    conarray a;
    //a.getNum1();
    //a.getNum2();
    //a.merge();
    //a.display();
    a.disp();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `d=0` should be within function body.

Comment: `d=0` is an initialization. Try putting that in the constructor

Comment: "Run the code to see where the problem lies." No. You please describe it and provide  any correponding information (e.g. error message) directly. Including to identify any line referenced by compile time messages (errors/warnings). By the way, running is impossible if there is a compiler error.

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff If you phrase that without a "try" you can turn that into a decent answer. (Ideally test your solution yourself, then skipping the "try" should not be a problem.)

Comment: Why do you have 2 identical classes `array1` and `array2`, kind of defeats the purpose of classes.